# Spork won't reload file in lib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, spork

I'm running rspec with spork and I can't get a file in lib to reload on consecutive rspec runs. I've tried require'ing the file in 'Spork.each_run'

I'm not getting any responses, so I'll try to explain further. I have the following files in my Rails app:

- lib/car.rb
- spec/lib/car_spec.rb

To run tests, first I start spork then run 'rspec spec/lib/car_spec.rb'

RSpec is not seeing my changes to my Car class, unless I restart spork.

Any help?

I'm on:

- rails 3.1.0.rc6
- rspec 2.6.0
- spork 0.9.0.rc9

Comment: Does it help if you add your lib directory to your reload_path e.g.:     config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You should put car.rb in `app/models`.

Comment: why? Certainly it is ok to place various extensions under lib, unless this particular car.rb file is actually an ActiveRecord::Model.

Answer (score 4):

Try to `load` that file in `Spork.each_run` instead of `require`.

Answer (score 1):

I hear you.  Reloading of files in lib/ is very important.

When I do a `require` directly (e.g. `require "some_dir_under_lib/some_file"`), it doesn't get reloaded automatically.  However, if I do

`Dir["some_dir_under_lib/*.rb"].each { |file| require file }`

then it DOES get reloaded automatically!  I wish I could explain why!

Btw, I'm doing that in application.rb, not in spork/spec_helper stuff.